# is it a good idea to reuse port using option SO_REUSEADDR which is already in TIME_WAIT state?

Tags: c, performance, sockets, tcp, sctp

I know there are already lot of questions on SO_REUSEADDR. Still I could not get its disdvantages and have few questions.

1]what is the danger associated with SO_REUSEADDR when we are not using any linger option.

2]Will there be any packet loss scenario?

3]What happens if i get something on the port which in time wait state?

4]What will happen to that packet which was received in TIME_WAIT?

and last but very important

5]Is there any performance impact of having lot many ports in TIME_WAIT state at any point of time?

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage is that you might receive data that was intended for an earlier connection and not related to the new connection, corrupting that communication session.  The whole point of `TIME_WAIT` is to allow the OS to flush out lingering data.  If a packet is received for a IP/Port in `TIME_WAIT` state, the packet is discarded.  By using `SO_REUSEADDR`, you bypass that safety catch.

If you have a lot of ports in `TIME_WAIT` state, you can cause port exhaustion, which prevents new connections from being established until ports in `TIME_WAIT` clear up.

Comment: port exhaustion is very rare scenario in my case i can max have 1000 or say 2000 connection. but say if i have 100-200 port in time wait state. will it make any impact on performance. since in this case i will be TCP control block for each port which is in time wait state. my concern is , will that effect be a considerable one?